# How to correctly say "I attach great importance to documenting my code."

Tags: sentence-construction

A friend explained me that the sentence `I attach great importance to documenting my work." sounds french. I can I better say so?

The context is a cover letter in which I would like to express some strengths I have in my field of expertise.

Comment: I don't understand what your friend meant by "it sounds French".  It doesn't sound French to this native US English speaker!  You might want to ask your friend to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have many options for communicating that same point, although that sentence is not wrong or even difficult to understand. If you want some alternatives:

> I think it is very important to document my work

or

> I find documenting my work very important

or

> I think it very important to document my work

or

> I place great importance on documenting my work

or

> I always document my work; I think it's important to do so.